# comparing ArrayList of Strings with Array of Strings

Tags: java, arrays, list, arraylist

i am trying to compare array list of string with array of string by using .equal but its not working i am trying to remove element from array list if it is equal to arrays element every time it is executing if part and not removing element from array list

```
    public ArrayList removeCommonWords(ArrayList<String> fileTokens){
    System.err.println("size of arraylist: \t"+fileTokens.size()+"\t size of array: \t"+stoppingWordsGlobal.length);
    for(int i=0;i<fileTokens.size();i++){
        for (int j=0;j<stoppingWordsGlobal.length;j++) {
            if (fileTokens.get(i).equals(stoppingWordsGlobal[j])) {
                fileTokens.remove(i);
                System.out.print("\nremoving token number :"+"\t"+i+"\t"+fileTokens.get(i)+"\t"+stoppingWordsGlobal[j]);
            }
        } 
    }
    return fileTokens;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Convert the `String[] stringArray` to an `ArrayList<String>`:

```
ArrayList<String> strings = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(stringArray));
```

Then simply remove shared content from the original list:

```
originalList.removeAll(strings);
```

Or in one line (untested):

```
originalList.removeAll(new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(stringArray));
```

Comment: but the same code on the an other program is working fine.. i think its not necessary or it is?

Comment: No but it's shorter and easier.

Comment: you are checking two arrays are equal or not and i am asking how to remove elements from array list if any element of array is equal to element of array list

Answer (score 0):

Try  this:

```
main method code:

ArrayList<String> list= new ArrayList<String>();
      list.add("angularjs");
      list.add("javascript");
      list.add("java");
      list.add("c");

     Test test= new Test();
     System.out.println(test.removeCommonWords(list));
```

your method:

```
String[] stoppingWordsGlobal={"nodejs","java","angularjs"};
    public ArrayList removeCommonWords(ArrayList<String> fileTokens){
        System.err.println("size of arraylist: \t"+fileTokens.size()+"\t size of array: \t"+stoppingWordsGlobal.length);
        for(int i=0;i<fileTokens.size();i++){
            for (int j=0;j<stoppingWordsGlobal.length;j++) {
                if (fileTokens.get(i).equals(stoppingWordsGlobal[j])) {
                    String removedString=fileTokens.get(i);
                    fileTokens.remove(i);
                    System.out.print("\nremoving token number :"+"\t"+i+"\t"+removedString+"\t"+stoppingWordsGlobal[j]);
                }
            } 
        }
        return fileTokens;
    }
```

output is:

size of arraylist:  4    size of array:     3

removing token number : 0   angularjs   angularjs

removing token number : 1   java        java

Comment: i am doing already exactly this but it is not removing i mean if part is working every time either it is equal or not equal.......

Comment: It is working fine from my side and returning the arraylist with removed elements. in your method ,you were trying to print the value after removing the element.